# How to rasterize a line in memory without displaying rendered image?

Tags: opengl, gpgpu, antialiasing, rasterizing, openvg

I am trying to use GPGPU for some (scientific) calculations.

Essentially, I need to rasterize (with antialiasing) a (bountiful of) line(s) cutting a grid, and save this data in a sparse format (that will later be handled by CUDA or alike). I believe Xiaolin Wu's line would do the work, for example (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xiaolin_Wu%27s_line_algorithm).

My question is: can I use OpenGL/OpenVG/NV_path_rendering library to do it for me (fast and efficiently) *without* producing a display output, but only storing float values on a memory array of given resolution (width-height) so I can later process it?

I only have little experience with OpenGL and it always had a window or something that I really don't want in this case.

Comment: In OpenGL, you can render to a framebuffer object, then the result is stored in a texture which can be read back. This would not *display* the rendered line, but you still need a OpenGL context which might (depending on your OS) require a window handle.

Comment: I see. I will check it in more details. Although my current environment is windows (which I suspect requires a window handler), the target system is Linux, which should be ok. Thanks a lot!